# Appending strings to a list in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Say I have a text file like that where every new letter starts on a new line:

```
-.H
-.e
-.l
-.l
-.o
```

I would like to write a code to remove some data from each text line (in the case of example I would like to remove '-.' in front of each letter) and then concatenate the result back together to form:

```
Hello
```

What would be a general approach to this kind of problem? I thought it could be solved in a following way:

```
f = open('hello.txt', 'r')
logs = f.readlines()
f.close()
loglist = list(map(str.strip, logs))
newlist = []

for i in range (len(loglist)):
    splitLetter = loglist[i].split('.')
    letter = splitLetter[-1]
    newlist.append(letter)
    word = ''.join(newlist)
    print word
```

The problem though is that the result is a series of iterations:

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
```

I need only the last result. How do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you are printing after every iteration. By moving the `print` statement outside of the for-loop it will print only the last iteration.

```
f = open('hello.txt', 'r')
logs = f.readlines()
f.close()
loglist = list(map(str.strip, logs))

word = ''.join(l.split('.')[-1] for l in loglist)
print word
```

Just to make sure this works, I tested it out with a test file with the following text:

```
-.G
-.o
-.o
-.d
-.b
-.y
-.e
```

and got the following result:

```
Goodbye
```

Comment: Well yes, that should be self-explanatory. I feel bad now for asking this question here. :D Sometimes brain stops functioning properly after long coding hours.

Comment: @kevin you can remove [ ] inside join, `''.join(l.split('.')[-1] for l in loglist)`

Answer (score 0):

Just move the printing outside of the loop:

```
for i in range (len(loglist)):
    splitLetter = loglist[i].split('.')
    letter = splitLetter[-1]
    newlist.append(letter)

word = ''.join(newlist)
print word
```

Comment: LOL @ the rage-queen that downvoted everyone two months after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (len(loglist)):
    splitLetter = loglist[i].split('.')
    letter = splitLetter[-1]
    newlist.append(letter)
word = ''.join(newlist)
print word
```

or

```
word = ''
for i in range (len(loglist)):
    splitLetter = loglist[i].split('.')
    letter = splitLetter[-1]
    word += letter
print word
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = ''.join([ l.split('.')[-1] for l in loglist ])
```

instead of the whole `for` loop should do.

Comment: Great and short solution to the problem. I still need for loop because I intend to apply conditionals.

Comment: You can use conditionals (`if` clause) in list comprehension, too. Unless of course you need to assign to temporary variables - assignments can't be done within list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the result in every step. Simply print after the for loop.

You can use generator expressions for shorter program:

```
with open('hello.txt') as logs:
    word = ''.join(l.strip().split('.')[-1] for l in logs)
print word
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `with ... as` statement frees you from closing the file. It will be automatically closed at the end of the block.

Then, in one single line:
`word = ''.join([l.strip()[-1]] for l in logs)`

You don't need to split the string if you strip the string before. You can be sure the letter will be at the last index.

**Full code**:

```
with open('hello.txt', 'r') as logs:
    word = ''.join([l.strip()[-1]] for l in logs)
print word
```